# Jenkins publish junit xml from remote test pc

Tags: jenkins, junit, pytest

I can publish junit xml reports when I run test on same box as Jenkins with pytest. It works great.

Now I am running pytest on a remote test pc initiated Jenkins. It runs a series of python tests and generates the junit xml report on remote test pc. Where I am stuck is how to push those junit xml report back to Jenkins?

The test PC is Windows 10. I currently launch the tests remotely via powershell commands to initiate the pytest. I don't have a Jenkins slave agent on the remote test pc.

Comment: You should specify what Operating Systems are on these PC's. There's [Copy To Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) but it has security problems. You might have to use an OS based utility.

Comment: If you're using Jenkins 2 and pipelines, you can copy files between master and slaves via `stash/unstash` functions.

Comment: I updated my question with operating system installed at the test pc

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of copying a file from one node to another using stash / unstash. The file 'foo.jar' is in '/tmp' on the source system, and will end up in '/tmp' on the target system.

```
stage ('Stash file on node 1') {
    node ('node1') {
        dir ('/tmp') {
            stash name: 'TestTransfer', includes: 'junit.xml'
        }
    }
}

stage ('Unstash file on node 2') {
    node ('node2') {
        dir ('/tmp') {
            unstash 'TestTransfer'
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of copying a file from node 1 to the master, and then archiving it as an artifact, so that you can view it or download it from the GUI after job completion

```
stage ('Stash file on node 1') {
    node ('node1') {
        dir ('/tmp') {
            stash name: 'TestTransfer', includes: 'junit.xml'
        }
    }
}

stage ('Unstash file on master') {
    node () {
        // By default, goes to the workspace.
        // If you want to go to a directory, wrap in 'dir'
        unstash 'TestTransfer'
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*'
    }
}
```